# Add a kernel parameter with sed to grub

Tags: linux, bash, hibernate, shell, sed

I'm writing a bash script to non-interactively enable hibernation on a linux system. To this end, I need to insert a shell variable that contains slashes on a specific line of a while, inside quotes that are on that line.

The relevant part of the file to b edited looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Manjaro"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I need to change it to this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Manjaro"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/c5a552c2-fe8f-423a-9037-c35bf090d9c3"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The added parameter is provided by a shell variable.

I tried this:

```
sed -i '\*^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT* s*"$* '"$(grub_resume_boot_option)"'"*' /etc/default/grub
```

Logic that I was aiming for was: "Look for a line that starts with pattern "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT", and replace the last " with the given pattern. Use * as delimiter to preserve the slashes in the expanded variable."

However, the command fails if there are any spaces at the end of the line. Is there any way to make it not take spaces at the end of the line into account?

Also, if there is more simple or readable solution to this, I would be very interested.

Comment: How do you determine the value for `resume=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/c5a....` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
sed -i 's#^\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet\)"$#\1 resume=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/c5a552c2-fe8f-423a-9037-c35bf090d9c3"#' /etc/default/grub
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed 's#^\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet\)"$#\1 resume=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/c5a552c2-fe8f-423a-9037-c35bf090d9c3"#' <<<'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/c5a552c2-fe8f-423a-9037-c35bf090d9c3"
```

Comment: This assumes you know the entire contents of the line, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

From: https://serverfault.com/questions/885684/editing-the-value-of-grub-cmdline-linux-default-thru-bash-script

```sh
sed -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&newstuff /' /etc/default/grub
```

This will add "newstuff" to the beginning of the list of params. Examples:

```
sed 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&newstuff /' <<< 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="newstuff quiet"
```

```
sed 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&newstuff /' <<< 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="newstuff quiet splash"
```

Comment: This also worked nicely for enabling cgroups2 which is the non default line.

```
sudo sed -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="/&systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 /' /etc/default/grub
```
Example:
```
sed 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="/&systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 /' <<< 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 "
```

Never knew you could inline test via sed like that. super cool thanks for sharing that @user357269

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[^"]*/& $(grub_resume_boot_option)/" /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over, say, the top-voted answer? Can you explain what you're doing?